# Delphi, не сработает событие KeyDown при нажатии Ctrl+C

Tags: delphi

В IDE делаю ToolForm на ней есть обычная панель у панели есть событие при нажатии клавиатуры.

Если поочередно нажимать клавиши - они срабатывают, а при комбинации например Ctrl+C - нет. Наверное IDE зарезервировала комбинацию и событие не проходит.

Как же все-таки получить событие?

решил через SetWindowsHookEx если у кого есть вариант получше напишите.

Comment: У панели нет события на нажатие клавы.

Comment: @MBo есть панель это Wincontrol. как же тогда я получая события нажатия отдельных клавиш проблема ток с комбинацией

Comment: Где?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2JpR.png

Comment: @ MBo вот здесь type TLocWinControl= class(TWinControl); ... TLocWinControl(Panel5).OnKeyDown:=FormKeyDown;

Comment: @Mbo а еще тута и тута   TMyPanel = class (TPanel)
   private
      procedure WMKeyDown(var Message: TWMKeyDown); message WM_KEYDOWN;
   protected
      procedure KeyDown( var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);  override;

Comment: @Mbo ток еще при нажатии мыши на панель ей фокус нужно установить TPanel.SetFocus

Comment: Так у вас не стандартная TPanel

Comment: @Mbo это не важно я задаю вопрос про стандартную и вам еще показал как в стандартной получить эти события да и какая разница обычная она или нет. TPanel это TWinControl да даже дело не в TPanel Блин зачем вы пишите абы написать. ЛЮБОЙ TWINCONTROL МОЖЕТ ПОЛУЧИТЬ СОБЫТИЯ О ВВОДЕ КЛАВЫ и не важно стандартный он или нет. Проснитесь))

Comment: @vegat4, у меня нет Delphi под рукой, есть только Lazarus 2.2.2 (Freepascal). Он частично совместим с Delphi, и в нём я нормально получаю нажатие комбинаций от панели.

Comment: @Old Skull вы это делаете в designtime на форме унаследованной от TDesignWindow? если в runtime то там у меня тож проблем нет. скорее всего режим разработки захоткеил клавиши и поэтому нет события но я уже это решил повесив хук на клаву через SetWindowsHookEx

Comment: Вопрос про VCL или FMX?